# React sending array of objects as form Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, form-data

I have currently created a nodejs api where a user can send data about their career. They can send text and an uploaded image.

The data is sent as follows and I have been successful with sending via postman

```
{
    "employee": "user",
    "positionHeld": [{
        "yearPostitionHeld": "1995 - 2000",
        "positionHeldTitle": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "yearPostitionHeld": "2000 - Present",
        "positionHeldTitle": "Assocaite Manager"
    }],
    "address": "Company Address",
    "responsibilities": ["Responsibility 1", "Responsibility 2", "Responsibility 3"]
}
```

I have created a front end page with ReactJS so the user can send the data as above by filling in input fields.

I set the user input via the useState Hook

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    companyName: "",
    year: "",
    positionHeld: [
      {
        positionHeldYear: "",
        positionHeldTitle: "",
      },
    ],
    address: "",
    responsibilities: "",
  });
```

via an onChange function

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

I also hanle the file upload

```
const [fileData, setFileData] = useState();

const handleFilechange = (e) => {
    setFileData(e.target.files[0]);
  };
```

I first tried to send the data as the `formData` but the file/image always appeared in req.body and not req.file and therefore I was unable to obtain the file path.

As a solution to the file issue I then create a new formData `const completeFormData = new FormData();` and appending this

```
const year = formData.positionHeldYear;
    const title = formData.positionHeldTitle;
    setFormData({...formData, positionHeld: {positionHeldYear: year, positionHeldTitle: title}})

completeFormData.append("companyName", formData.companyName);
    completeFormData.append("year", formData.year);
    completeFormData.append("positionHeld", formData.positionHeld); // this needs to send the array of objects
    completeFormData.append("address", formData.address);
    completeFormData.append("responsibilities", formData.responsibilities);
    completeFormData.append("image", fileData);
```

I am unsure if it is possible to send an array of objects as the new FormData such as the

```
"positionHeld": [{
        "yearPostitionHeld": "1995 - 2000",
        "positionHeldTitle": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "yearPostitionHeld": "2000 - Present",
        "positionHeldTitle": "Assocaite Manager"
    }],
```

When creating the new form data as above when the req.body comes to the backend the `positionHeld` displays as `positionHeld: [object, Object]` when doing a console log

How is it best to manage sending data with nest array of object strings and image uploads?

I might have gone down the wrong route with this, so hoping someone can point me in the right direction to send body and a file to confirm as my object

```
{
    "employee": "user",
    "positionHeld": [{
        "yearPostitionHeld": "1995 - 2000",
        "positionHeldTitle": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "yearPostitionHeld": "2000 - Present",
        "positionHeldTitle": "Assocaite Manager"
    }],
    "address": "Company Address",
    "responsibilities": ["Responsibility 1", "Responsibility 2", "Responsibility 3"]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of sending an array in FormData is to serialize it:

```
completeFormData.append("positionHeld", JSON.stringify(formData.positionHeld));
```

Then, on the backend, you can parse it with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: That done the trick, thank you. I had previously done JSON.stringify on the front end but never parsed it on the back end. Thank you. My next thought would have been to save the images to a new collection and reference them in my other collect but stringifying and parsing solved it

Answer (score 2):

We did it with ReactJS(front) and ASP.Net core(back) So the best way to do it is using FormData, We use an object like below that contains an array of objects, each object includes an array of images too,

```
{
    CommodityID:xxxxx,
    TotalWeight:xxxx,
    CostOfCommodity:xxxx,
    Prerequisites:[{
        ProductId: xxxx,
        DeliveryWeight: xxxxx,
        ReleasedImagesUrl: [
            multiple images file
        ]
    },{
        ProductId: xxxx,
        DeliveryWeight: xxxxx,
        ReleasedImagesUrl: [
            multiple images file
        ]
    }]
}
```

Actually, we send each item of the array separately like `Prerequisites[0].DeliveryWeight` and this is the point (pairs of name/value). please pay attention to the letters that in our case first characters of items were capital (this is important too)

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("CommodityID", this.state.commodityId);
    formData.append("TotalWeight", this.state.totalWeight);
    formData.append("CostOfCommodity",this.state.costOfCommodity);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.prerequisitesListTemp.length; i++) {
      formData.append(
        `Prerequisites[${i}].ProductId`,
        this.state.prerequisitesListTemp[i].productId
      );
      formData.append(
        `Prerequisites[${i}].DeliveryWeight`,
        this.state.prerequisitesListTemp[i].deliveryWeight
      );

      for (
        let j = 0;j < this.state.prerequisitesListTemp[i].releasedImagesUrl.length;j++
      ) {
        formData.append(
          `Prerequisites[${i}].ReleasedImagesUrl`,
          this.state.prerequisitesListTemp[i].releasedImagesUrl[j]
        );
      }
    }
```