# React Axios multipart/form-data Array not Working

Tags: reactjs, arrays, axios, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a collection of data through Axios which contains image, so I have to use multipart/form-data. When I try to send an array data, the result I got is just an empty array. I am using Axios version 1.6.5, it should have Automatic serialization. I have no idea what am I missing. This is my code in React.js:

```
import AxiosInstance from "../Axios";
.....
AxiosInstance.post(`manager/`, {
  title: data.title,
  url: data.url,
  date: date,
  category: data.category,
  level: ["easy", "medium"], //to make sure I send array 
  scope: data.scope,
  image: data.image,
  description: data.description,
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

This is what I got in the result:

```
data: 
  category: false
  created: "2024-01-27T17:58:38.028124Z"
  date: "2024-01-31"
  description: "Testing only"
  id: 17
  image: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/manager/Testing.jpg"
  level: []
  scope: true
  slug: "test"
  title: "test"
  updated: "2024-01-27T17:58:38.028124Z"
  url: "https://test.com
```

I tried to send the data from Postman to make sure it was not my backend problem and I worked fine. This is what I tried in Postman
[image]

How to implement this in the Axios? What am I missing?

I really appreciate your help, thank you in advance!

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942422/10535718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FormData()` It supportarray data like level: ["easy", "medium", "hard"] in React Component

Snippet code

```js
const [levels, setLevels] = useState(["easy", "medium", "hard"]);
const formData = new FormData();
levels.forEach(level => formData.append('level[]', level));

const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/manager', formData, {
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
});
```

OR New [Automatic serialization method](https://github.com/axios/axios#-automatic-serialization-to-formdata)

```js
const [levels, setLevels] = useState(["easy", "medium", "hard"]);
const [image, setImage] = useState("http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/manager/Testing.jpg");

const formData = {
    levels: levels,
    image: image
};

const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/manager', formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
});
```

#### Demo

##### #1 `node.js` Server using `express` library

Specially `multer` library support `form-data`
Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
const upload = multer();
app.use(express.json());

// Middlewares
app.use(cors()); // For cross-origin resource sharing

app.post('/manager', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
    const levels = req.body.level;
    const image = req.body.image;
    // Other passing data add in here
    // ex) title = req.body.title;

    console.log('Received levels:', levels);
    console.log('Received image:', image);

    // Handle your array data and image as needed here
    // ...

    // Sending back a JSON response
    res.json({ levels: levels, image: image });
});


// Server listening
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

---

#### Install server Dependencies

```
npm install express cors multer
```

##### Run Server

```
node server.js
```

---

##### POST Call Testing by Postman

To check array and image URL testing

[image]

---

##### FormComponent in React

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const FormComponent = () => {
    const [levels, setLevels] = useState(["easy", "medium", "hard"]);
    const [image, setImage] = useState("http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/manager/Testing.jpg");

    const [responseMessage, setResponseMessage] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = {
            levels: levels,
            image: image
        };

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/manager', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });
            console.log(response.data);
            setResponseMessage(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)); // Formatting JSON for display
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
            setResponseMessage('Error: Could not get a response.');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <button type="submit">Submit Levels</button>
            </form>
            {responseMessage && <p>Server Response: {responseMessage}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

---

##### Before Post Call (or Before button click)

[image]

##### After Post Call

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, but I think the Axios should perform the formData by Axios serializer internally: https://github.com/axios/axios#-automatic-serialization-to-formdata. However, this feature is not working in mine. Am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: Did you reproduce my demo code? How to reproduce your code. You need to provide minimum reproduce code.

Comment: @Dra-Code, I tested the Automatic serialization way also works for me I added at the top, Thanks!

Comment: @Dra-Code,  I think you missed   the  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } part.

Comment: Well I found the problem this is actually a backend problem. I feel stupid because I am using Django multiselectfield for the levels, and when I read more about that it said it is CharField of comma-separated values, that's why the array cannot send properly. So I have to use FormData but without brackets (because it is not array actually). Since I cannot use Automatic serializer and your formData forEach solution quite useful, I accept your answer. Thank you, and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Good job finding a problem at the backend, I am happy to hear about your problem solving and we learned from each other back and force communication. Specialty I learned  Automatic serialization and how to send/receive a array of data.